# My app crashes when it go back foreground only in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

The question is:

1. Every time the app go back foreground it will crash on iOS 10
2. The app works fine on other version iOS

Before I asked the question here,I had try:

1. Search answers on google and this site
2. Go to the info.plist and add `NSCalendarsUsageDescription`
3. Turn on the background modes
4. Delete another app with the same product name but different bundle ID  on my iPhone6
5. Check "Zombie objects" and "Malloc Scribble" in Edit Scheme's Memory Management.

The crash results I can see is:

1. The console just show "(lldb)"
2. There is a breakpoint with a message:

> Thread 27:EXC_BreakPointCode=1,subcode=0*10121

I had try my best to make this question more clear.What confused me most is that the app just crash on iOS10.

Hope someone could help me.

Comment: Have you tried setting breakpoints in your app delegate in `applicationWillEnterForeground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` and stepping through the code from there?

Comment: write  your console display crash error reason.

Comment: Even if I delete all the code in  applicationWillEnterForeground and applicationDidBecomeActive,it will crash like before.

Comment: I'm sorry the console just display '(lldb)',no more infomation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be it is related to any privacy issue if you accessing any of this framework

Calendar , Contact , Reminder , Photo , Bluetooth Sharing , Microphone , Camera , Location , Heath , HomeKit , Media Library , Motion , CallKit , Speech Recognition , SiriKit , TV Provider

so you need to add the privacy key in plist in IOS 10

so here is the link which will help full for you. [LINK](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html)

Comment: Before I ask this question I had tried what you said,but it no use.

Comment: By the way,the link you gave is very helpful.Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

At last I find the reason is that there is a old 3 part that didn't fit iOS 10.After I update the old 3 part to it's newest version,the app works fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "old 3 part"? Please explain in brief so anyone can understand what was the issue.

Comment: @V.J.   old 3 part means non-system framework.....I'm sorry it makes people puzzled，but it's none of my business because this is what my teacher told me......0.0